# how to efficiently do the name refactoring in karate framework?

Tags: api, rest, ui-automation, karate

Seems name refactoring not that easy in Karate framework. I tried in both IntelliJ and VSCode
Could you please suggest some workaround for same

Eg: If I am calling a feature file at multiple places and in case I want to rename it I would need to rename explicitly file name wherever it has been used.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a limitation of the existing plugins. The official IntelliJ plugin has JSON validation and this feature is planned, but not yet released: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19232-karate